# print value of environment variable from a file

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

**Problem Description**

In my Unix ksh system, I am having an environment variable A on doing

`echo ${A}`

I am getting the desired value which is `hello`.

I can check this value in

`env | grep ${A}`

output: `A=hello`

or in

`printenv | grep ${A}`

output: `A=hello`

Now I have a file `file` which contains the list of environment variables and I have to fetch the corresponding value.

Now what I tried just for only first value of the file.

1. `env | grep $(cat file | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')`  --shows nothing
2. `b=$(cat file | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')`

   `env | grep echo $b`
3. `b=cat TEMP_ES_HOST_MAP | awk -F"|" 'NR==1{print $2 }'`
   `echo $b`
   `c=`eval $b
   c=`echo $b`

Nothing seems to be working.

Thank you

Comment: A shorter/simpler option could be to use eval: `varname=A; eval "echo \$$varname"`

Comment: @Wolph Not the same though. That finds variables that aren't exported also.

Comment: Related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/use-a-variable-reference-inside-another-variable

Comment: @EtanReisner: true, it's not identical. Might be enough for this case though :)

Comment: @Wolph Thanks for reply, but this is not working :(

Comment: Your `awk` commands indicate you are confusing `NR` (record/row number) and `NF` (field number).

Comment: @chepner: I am taking first row only with NR==1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
awk -F '[$()]+' '{print $1$2}' envfile | xargs printenv
```

Where:

```
cat envfile
$(LANG)
$LINES
USER
HISTFILESIZE
```

Comment: I have tested this on `ksh`. Can you show a sample of `file`?

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: `xargs printenv < envfile`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the *variable* named `A` in the output from `env` and `printenv` then using `grep ${A}` is incorrect (and unsafe/does not work for variables of more than one word).

What you want for that is:

```
env | grep ^A=
printenv | grep ^A=
```

So assuming your file looks like this:

```
VAR1
VAR2
OTHER_VAR
```

and you want to search for those you could use something like this (assuming you have process substitution):

```
env | grep -f <(awk '{print "^"$0"="}' varfile)
```

Assuming you don't have process substitution (or you would rather a simpler solution, I do) you can do this:

```
env | awk -F = 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' varfile -
```

Actually this should work too and is even simpler (assuming an awk with `ENVIRON`):

```
awk '$1 in ENVIRON {print $1"="ENVIRON[$1]}' varfile
```